# Visual Studio Code - Property expected Jsonc (513) [54,101]

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

New to coding. I'm learning online and I was following footsteps from a teacher on visual studio-code as they told me to edit the default settings in code-runner.executorMap. Whilst doing so, i've accidentally pressed or removed something. Down below on (problems), it keeps showing the following - Property expected json (513) [54,101] showing up on problems.

Need help if possible, thank you. [visual studio-code property expected (513) image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAYuT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON files must follow a certain format, you can refer to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_syntax.htm

According to your screenshot, you have an extra comma `,` at the cursor position in the figure, and you missed a closing brace afterwards `}`

You can also refer to my default settings:

[My default settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzKo9.png)

In addition, it is best not to modify the default settings of vscode, but to modify the user settings, the best reference is

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings